# French accents with android

Tags: android

How can I use the é accent in android or french accents at all?
I am developing with android studio and when I enter é, as I'm used to with other editors, nothing happens.
When I enter

```
&eacute;
```

I get "Unsolved entity reference eacute".

```
&amp;
```

is workin though. Do I have to load some language settings?
Thanks

Comment: Where would you like to enter accented characters?

Comment: Why comes that I can use them? German, French, Italian and Spanish special characters without any issue.

Comment: I would like to use them in the strings.xml files.

Comment: Make sure your file is saved with **UTF-8** encoding (`Save As` options). Also make sure that it includes this line at the very top of it: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`.

Comment: Where do I find the Save As options?

Comment: I guess it's under File? Please note that I'm **not** notified of your comments. You should address me specifically (@BobMalooga). I can avoid that, because you are the original poster.